# SQLite: issue with SELECT * FROM Tble where?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, sqlite, local

I am working offline with SQLite, Javascript and Chrome
In my main page (main.html), I have two div: `<div id="menuLeft">` that contains the list of items name with buttons to edit each item, and

```
<div id="content">
```

The list of item is written as follows:

```
<li>ItemName1
    <div id="idItem1" class="editItem_btn">
        <img src="btn_edit.png">`
    </div>
</li>
```

In main.html, I have the following code:

```
$("#menuLeft").delegate(".editItem_btn", "click", function(e0)
     {
        e0.preventDefault();
        var editItemId = $(this).attr("id");
        editItemId = parseInt(editItemId);
        var url="edititem.html"
        $("#content").load(url,function(){
        loadRecord(editItemId);`
    });
});
```

When I click on the edit button of a given Item, the id of the Item is first retrieved from the id of the div around the edit button. Then I load the page edititem.html content. On success, I run the function loadRecord(editItemId), where loadRecord(i) is contained in edititem.html:

```
function loadRecord(j) 
{
    var item = dataset.item(j);
    idItem.value = item['id'];
    ItemName.value = item['ItemName'];
    dateStart.value = item['dateStart'];
    dateEnd.value = item['dateEnd'];
    notes.value = item['notes'];
}
```

This function enables to display the parameters of Item (id, ItemName....) contained in the database.

Here is my problem, the code works but in a weird way meaning that if I click on the edit button of Item1, the parameters of Item2 are displayed. Same thing if I click on edit Item2, parameters of Item3 are displayed.

I then replaced:

```
var item = dataset.item(j);
```

with:

```
var item = dataset.item(j-1);
```

and that works. But I need to understand why it's behaving like that, and why I need to use (j-1). I placed some alert() in the jquery code to check that I have the right editItemId number, and in the function loadRecord(j). The right id number is retrieved after the click and the right id number is passed to the function. I have no idea what's the bug here!

Comment: Please take more care over your posts. 6 months is more than enough time to learn how Markdown formatting works, and more than enough time to notice that there's a preview pane visible before you submit a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the sql side of things, and how that data is passed back to your script it's impossible to tell you exactly what's happening, but this is simply a case of some lists being 0 based and some lists being 1 based.  For example, arrays are generally 0 based (unless you specifically create them a different way), but $("#id").each(function(Index)... is 1 based.  You just have to know what you're working with and occasionally do as you have found and use -1 or +1 when relevant.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with the intricacies of SQLite, I suspect that `dataset.item(j)`:

- is accepting a 0-based index
- that you are passing in the record_id (which in itself is not actually an array index)
- and that the record_id for the dataset you are testing just happens to be the index + 1 (meaning you're getting lucky right now and that it will probably change when the next dataset is loaded).

I would check to see if there's an equivalent for `dataset.item(j)` which accepts a record_id and not an index. Otherwise, you'll probably want to store the index of the record somewhere in the record itself to be able to pass it to your `loadRecord` function.

Hope this helps,

Pete